# How can I make sure a specific string exists in every table row using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm a beginner at JavaScript and haven't been able to figure this out...

I need to check each row of a table to see if the string "Business Cards" exists in each row. If EVERY row contains this string, I'll proceed with option A, but if even one row doesn't contain the string, I'll stop checking and proceed with option B.

Here is an idea of what the table looks like in HTML (although the number of rows and products in each row will vary, since they're dynamically generated):

```
<table class="rgMasterTable" border="0" id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00" style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;empty-cells:show;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:center;">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:center;">No. of Units</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00__0" style="text-align:center;">
            <td style="width:250px;">
                Business Cards - TEST - CA Back
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px;">
                250 Business Cards
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00__1" style="text-align:center;">
            <td style="width:250px;">
                Business Cards - Joint Venture - TEST
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px;">
                250 Business Cards
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's my attempt at the code. I'm trying to make use of the fact that the tr id will always have the index (eg: "ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00__0" for the first row, "ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00__1" for the second, etc), but maybe there's an easier way to do this?

```
var businessCardItem = 'Business Cards';
var orderItemCount = $('#ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00 tr').length;
var onlyBusinessCards = true;

for (var i = 0; i <= orderItemCount; i++) {
    if($('#ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00__' + i).text().indexOf(businessCardItem) >= 0) {
        return onlyBusinessCards;
    }
    else {
        onlyBusinessCards = false;
        return onlyBusinessCards;
        break;
    }
} 

if (onlyBusinessCards == true) {
    //Option A
}
else {
    //Option B
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if any more detail or clarification is needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count how many rows contain "Business Cards" and compare to the number of rows:

Note: only count rows within `tbody`

```
var table = $("#ctl00_cphMainContent_dgShippingItems_ctl00");
var rows = $("tbody tr",table).length;
var rowsWithBC = $("tbody tr:contains(Business Cards)",table).length;

if( rows == rowsWithBC ) {
    // Option A
} else {
    // Option B
}
```